# Composer installation requirements

Tags: php, linux, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install composer to the laravel project.
When im doing `sudo composer install` in projects directory it shows me two errors:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode dev-master -> satisfiable by simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode[dev-master].
    - simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode dev-master requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for esendex/sdk ^1.3 -> satisfiable by esendex/sdk[v1.3.0].
    - esendex/sdk v1.3.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
```

I was checking how to install it and I found these commands:

1. `composer require simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode`
2. `composer require esendex/sdk`

Anyway, they are giving me the same error. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Do you have the PHP extentions  `ext-gd` and `ext-curl` installed on your system?

Comment: Reading the error message might help. Install the missing extensions and try again.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.4, for example, offers php-gd and php-curl system packages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you have some PHP modules missing.

### For PHP5

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

### For PHP7

```
sudo apt-get install php7-curl
sudo apt-get install php7-gd
```

> Packages may be different depending on your OS

Comment: It showed me that php5-curl could not be found but I just wrote `sudo apt-get install php*-curl` and it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything I can do about it?

Yes. You can install the two PHP modules that Composer tells you are required:

> - simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode dev-master requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
> - esendex/sdk v1.3.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

Exactly how you do that will depend on your operating system.

Ubuntu 16.10, for example, offers `php-gd` and `php-curl` system packages.