# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**THE BASH CONTAINS:**

```
sudo docker run -it  --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd),target=/app composer bash
bash-4.4# composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode 2.0.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode 2.0.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode[2.0.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - 
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/date_timezone.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memory-limit.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
bash-4.4# sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
bash: sudo: command not found
bash-4.4#
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I resolve "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318709/how-can-i-resolve-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set)

Comment: Another Possible duplicate [Composer installation requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767210/composer-installation-requirements)

Comment: My system already has php-gd, it was an error inside image of docker instead.

Comment: Yes same issues but in the docker image not the host

Comment: Php-gd is installed but the problem is still there